# Why are the Guava -sources jars almost empty? (Needed for GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, maven, guava

The current version of the Google Guava libraries (10.0.1) are nicely deployed on Maven Central here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/

My GWT compiler keeps complaining e.g. "GWT Module com.google.common.Collect.gwt.xml not found in project sources or resources." which is no surprise, given it can't find the sources anywhere. There are -sources jar in Maven Central, too, but they contain no sources. Only some shell scripts and GWT module definitions.

Why are the source jars without sources and is there another weird way to get Guava 10.0.1 play with GWT and Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say the source jars are empty, are you talking about the [guava artifact](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/), or the [guava-gwt artifact](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-gwt/10.0.1/)? They don't seem empty to me. The guava-gwt.jar even contains the sources (GWT needs the sources to be present in the jar you depend on, not the -sources.jar).

According to [the Guava wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild), you simply need a dependency to the guava-gwt artifact (instead of guava).

Maybe a GWT expert can chime in, I haven't used it since last year.

Comment: Right, inspecting the guava-gwt artifact with a zip tool I see the source. My mistake was to explore them using the Eclipse Referenced Libaries, which seems to filter out all java source files. Thanks also for directing my right to the right wiki page -- somehow I haven't stubmled over it.

Comment: Did the compiler work when you switched to the guava-gwt jar? I'm interested in how you solved this in the end. Did you simply switch the com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1 dependency to com.google.guava:guava-gwt:10.0.1? Or did you add both?

Comment: Currently I added both, I'll investigate why. The guava-gwt *should* suffice, I guess. I'll comment more.

Comment: Verified: guava-gwt suffices.

Comment: Cool, thanks for checking! I was worried that having both jars might cause classpath issues, since guava-gwt.jar differs slightly from guava.jar